# Build angular project into idea with maven

Tags: spring, angular, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

we are building SPA with Spring Boot Rest api and Angular 4. Here is our project structure in idea. It is small project, so we have it together. Project structure:
[image]

And here you are pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>custom-name</name>
    <description>Example App</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

We need help with configuration. Is possible to set up project that, when we run mvn clean package, then project is compile and build, and angular project too. So next when we run project in idea, it start with SPA app on same server. We do not have a lot of experience with that configuration. Can you help us? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I'll tried configure pom.xml to build angular project into war, but index controller still not works. Error:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Dec 07 03:10:09 CET 2017 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

Here is war structure:

[image]

Servlet initializer:

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

And Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index.html";
    }

}
```

Comment: I use Jhipster for that or follow this course : https://www.udemy.com/angular-4-java-developers/learn/v4/content

Answer (score 0):

You can run npm tasks from maven. Please check the following link [NPM build using maven](https://kosbr.github.io/2016/10/09/angular-build.html)